# Eigenvectors of a vectorized tranpose matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonal-matrices

Given the permutation matrix $P\in\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ such that $P\mathop{\mathrm{vec}}(X)=\mathop{\mathrm{vec}}(X^T)$ for all $X\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, is there any closed form expression for the eigenvectors of $P$? Clearly, the matrix is symmetric as $P_{m,n}=P_{n,m}^T$ for general vectorized transpose matrices, and as such it must have real eigenvalues $\lambda_i \in\{-1,1\}$, thus if we find a basis for one subspace, the other quickly follows.

EDIT: Towards answering my own question, the -1 eigenspace is equivalent to a basis for $n\times n$ skew-symmetric matrices and the 1 eigenspace is a basis for symmetric matrices. The simplest basis for either is $v=\mathop{\mathrm{vec}}(\pm E_{ij}+E_{ji})$ for $i<j$, plus the diagonal basis $w=E_{ii}$ for the symmetric case, where the former can normalized by multiplication with $\sqrt{2}/2$.

Comment: By $P_{m,n}=P_{n,m}^T$ are you referring to the elementary matrix corresponding to row interchange between $m$ and $n$?  Which matrix are you asking for closed form expression of eigenvectors of?

Comment: I clarified my question. $P_{m,n}$ is a general vectorized transpose matrix, that is a matrix that when multiplied with the vectorization of a m by n matrix yields the vectorization of the transpose of that same matrix

Comment: By $P$ is a "vectorized transpose" you mean that $P\text{vec}(X)=\text{vec}(X^T)$ ? Then $P \in \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ not $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ right? Your big question is "is there a closed form expression for the eigenvectors of $P$?" right?

Comment: Yes, it should be $n^2$. And yes, that is my main question.